# how to check callback validation codeigniter duplicate database entry?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

This is my callback function, I want to check the database for duplicate value, I have tried a lot, but I can't get validation to work. I'm new to Codeigniter so any help would be appreciated!

```
    public function alias_exist_check()
    {
        $scol_code = $this->input->post('school_code');
        $user_id=$this->input->post('user_id');
        $query=$this->db->get_where('user_application',array('school_code'=>$scol_code,                                                                                 'user_id'=>$user_id));
        $row= $query->row_array();

        if(!$row['user_id']==$user_id && !$row['school_code']==$scol_code)
        {
            return TRUE;

        } else {

            $this->form_validation->set_message('alias_exist_check', 'Already exists.');
            return FALSE;                    
        }
    }
```

UPDATE1 ::
i tried this but its not working me help me if i wrote any mistakes.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('school_code', 'School Name','required','callback_alias_exist_check', 'trim|xss_clean'); $where = array(
  'school_code' => $this->input->post('school_code'),
  'user_id' => $this->input->post('post'));

if( ! $this->lawschool_model->alias_exist_check($where))
{
      $this->form_validation->set_message('alias_exist_check', 'Already exists.');
                            }
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $data['row']=  $this->lawschool_model->Getuser($data1);
      $data['row1']=  $this->lawschool_model->GetData1();
      $this->ag_auth->view('Home',$data);
    }
    else
    {
       $insert = $this->db->insert('user_application',$data);       

    if($insert==TRUE)
    {
        /*$idNum = $this->input->post('school_code');
        $data1 = $this->lawschool_model->upddata_school();*/

        $data['row'] =  $this->lawschool_model->Getuser($data1);
        $data['row1'] =  $this->lawschool_model->GetData1();
        $this->ag_auth->view('Home',$data);
     }
}
```

UPDATE2::finaly its works fine,here is my working code

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('school_code', 'School Name','required','callback_alias_exist_check1', 'trim|xss_clean'); 

   function alias_exist_check1($scol_code,$user_id)
   {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_application WHERE school_code = ? AND user_id = ?";
        $val = $this->db->query($sql,array($scol_code ,$user_id ));

        if ($val->num_rows)
        {               
          $this->form_validation->set_message('alias_exist_check', 'Already exists.');
          return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
          return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is school_code unique?

Comment: yes its unique value school_code

Answer (score 1):

Model

```
public function alias_exist($where)
{
    return $this->db->where($where)->count_all_results('user_application') > 0;
}
```

Controller

```
public function alias_exist_check()
{
    $where = array(
        'school_code' => $this->input->post('school_code'),
        'user_id'     => $this->input->post('user_id')
    );
    return ! $this->name_model->alias_exist($where);
}
```

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('school_code', 'School Name','required','callback_alias_exist_check', 'trim|xss_clean');

Comment: @user3439296 / sorry, modified

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('school_code', 'School Name','required','callback_alias_exist_check1', 'trim|xss_clean'); 
             function alias_exist_check1($scol_code,$user_id)
                 {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_application WHERE school_code = ? AND user_id = ?";
        $val = $this->db->query($sql,array($scol_code ,$user_id ));
        
        if ($val->num_rows) {    
          $this->form_validation->set_message('alias_exist_check', 'Already exists.');
         return TRUE;
        } else {
         return FALSE;
        }
       }

Answer (score 0):

The first function was not working because you tried to access post data from within the callback itself. This does not appear to work well with callbacks. This is because codeigniter will remove all post data from the request as soon as your run the form validator run method. It repopulates post data only when form processing is complete. Pass any extra parameters you need for you callback functions to work like this

```
callback_foo[bar]
```